# YouTube livestream video big head filter

Tags: video, image-processing, streaming

Some YouTubers use a certain video filter to make one's head looks bigger on their livestreams. I wonder what they use. For examples, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B9KKqLwtUiA&t=150s and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hFqrbTnrxik&t=89s .

[image: First Image]

[image: Second Image]

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a software effect, nor even an intentional effect, it's just a poor choice of camera/lens. Note both instances the anchor in the studio looks relatively normal, but the people being interviewed remotely are affected. They are more likely to be using webcams or even phones in a non-professional home setup.

It just looks like ill-advised use of a wide angle lens - known in the trade as the 'big nose, little ears' look, like a phone selfie.

This is technically a perspective issue, based on distance, which doesn't happen when you look at yourself in a mirror because the brain adapts without you being aware.
When viewed through a lens, though, your brain can't do this. What you're left with is a set of disproportionate distances *as percentages*. If the distance from camera to nose is 18" & camera to ears is 22", then the ratio of distances is quite large. If the camera is 6 feet from the nose, the ears are at 6'4" & the ratio of distances is much smaller.
In short, the further away the camera is, & consequently the longer the lens, the better [proportionally] you look. A webcam or phone has such a wide lens that to fill any decent portion of it you have to be far too close to it - big nose, little ears.
Some of this could have been improved if there had been a proper vision check before broadcast. Both interviewees are leaning into the camera. That's going to make shoulders & below look smaller too, for the same reasons. A decent producer would have got them to lean back & even crop their image slightly before going to the live stream.
Adding distance to camera & cropping is *exactly* the same thing as using a longer lens, except for reduced pixel count.

The second example isn't helped at all by the girl being so slightly built she has a disproportionately large head anyway [known, very unkindly, in the TV/Film industry as a 'lollipop head'*, which often needs special consideration when shooting precisely to prevent this over-emphasis.]

*<sub>Aplogoies, I don't make these up myself.</sub>